# Generalised solution for Amoeba's survival problem

Tags: probability-distributions

A population starts with a single amoeba. For this one and for the generations thereafter, there is a probability of $p$ that an individual amoeba will split to create two amoebas, and a $(1-p)$ probability that it will die out without producing offspring. Now, can we find a probability function at $n_{th}$ generation, which will let me know how many members will we find at that generation? For example, that at $2nd$ generation no member will survive has cumulative probability of $(1-p)+p(1-p)^2$. Also, what distribution will this follow?

Comment: What exactly do you want?  The expected number of amoebas in generation $n$?  The probability that there are no amoebas in generation $n$?  The probability distribution of generation $n$?  The first question is easy; I'm not sure about the others.

Comment: If I know the first one, I can know the second one. But I want to know if the first question follows any specific probability distribution. There is an answer below based on a recursive code, but I wanted to know if there was a generalised formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only two choices, the offspring number is either $0$ or $2$. So we model the problems as such: for non negative integers $n,k$ with $k\le 2^n$ and where $2^n-k$ is even, let $f(n,k)$ be the probability that the $n$-th generation yields an amoeba population of size $k$.

Then $f$ can be computed recursively as in the Maple code shown below.

[image]

Applying the recursion, here are the results for $0\le n\le 3$:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
n&k&f(n,k)\\
\hline
0&1&1\\
\hline
1&0&1-p\\
&2&p\\
\hline
2&0&1-2p^2+p^3\\
&2&2p^2-2p^3\\
&4&p^3\\
\hline
3&0&1-4p^3+2p^4+4p^5-4p^6+p^7\\
&2&4p^3-4p^4-8p^5+12p^6-4p^7\\
&4&2p^4+4p^5-12p^6+6p^7\\
&6&4p^6-4p^7\\
&8&p^7\\
\hline
\end{array}